# flutter how to align bottom of icon to the center of screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map function where I have an marker-Icon that always lays in the center of the screen with the help of the Align widget.
The problem is that i want the bottom of the Icon to be in the center, but now the middle of the Icon is in center.

I think that I have to some how offset verticaly by half of the Icon height, in my case 25 (50/2) if that is possible.

My code:

```
Align(
            child: Icon(
              ModernPictograms.location,
              size: 50,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center)
```

Comment: Try to add your current result

Comment: + can you include the parent widget

Comment: its just an empty stateless widget with an appbar. But I found the solution and posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, just use a Column, center it with mainaxisalignment and crossaxisalignment and inside the column a sized box:

```
Align(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  ModernPictograms.location,
                  size: 50,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center),
```

Comment: you can remove the Align widget

Comment: I see, good input!